# How to add "subscribe button" in facebook messenger bot?

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

I need to add a button (subscription ) in my messenger bot through which users can subscribe. and after that bot will automatically send latest post to the users at the specific time.
I was going through documentation but i am unable to find any proper documentation for it.
Can anybody please help regarding that?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook don't provide a mechanism to manage subscriptions. It's up to you as a developer to choose how to implement this - for example using a button with a payload to confirm that the user wants to opt in.

You could perhaps put an Opt Out option in your persistent menu and listen for the relevant payload and unsubscribe the user.

Facebook have published some documentation about this, explaining how they expect subscription messaging to be triggered:

> Person sends a message to a business or clicks on a call to action button within Messenger to request subscription messaging
>
> Person requests subscription messaging from a business via a Send to Messenger plugin
>
> Person signs up for SMS alerts

See the full page of documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview#messaging_types for more details on their expectation

Comment: Lets say, user says " Yes he want to subscribe."  But after that through what method i should set the timing for new message to be sent to the user. and How can i automatically send message to the user. does Facebook provide any help regarding that or do i have to implement a query for this?

Comment: You'll need to maintain some sort of data store - Facebook don't explain how to do this. One way is to have a database table with the recipients PSID, the time of when you want to send it and the message. Then query the table every X minutes to look for messages due to send.